# Mongo-go-driver error New client error ClientOptions in argument to mongo.NewClient

Tags: mongodb, go

i have try driver mongodb for a simple connection like on tutorial from this repos [github mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) i just write client like this :

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo"
    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/options"
)

var client *mongo.Client

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting the application...")
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

}
```

but show error :

cannot use "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/options".Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017") (type *"github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/options".ClientOptions) as type *"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options".ClientOptions in argument to mongo.NewClient

Driver version use V1.0.0

Any sugestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should not use `github` version of mongo driver. It is just fork of repo located here `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo`. So in first place `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo` and then your improts you should change

`github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/*`

to

`go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/*`